# Typo3 How do i get this DCE one div above?

Tags: html, typo3, fluid

quick question here:

I am using DCE on Typo 6.1.5. I am trying to set an element out of the "container" div. But it rarely works.

```
<div id="contentMarginFix">..</div>
<div id="contact">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="gmaps">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the "gmaps" div in the "contact" div. Not in the "container" one.

Here is the DCE Template

http://gyazo.com/2c0a13746cdd834ebdb86a0b64fd10b1.png

And here is the template for the page

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqQyk.jpg

I was trying for two hours now maybe i just don't see it but i appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshots you provided I'd say it's possible the layout template is in the wrong place. Make sure the contact.html you use as a layout is in the right place.

If this is a basic fluid template directly in typo3 make sure the file is in the place you defined in your setup typoscript. Default would be something like this:

```
layoutRootPath = fileadmin/templates/Layouts/
```

If this is inside an extension the correct place for the layout template is

```
Resources\Private\Layouts
```

Be aware that in more recent extbase versions the naming conventions are more strict and require a capital first letter for the html files (so Contact.html)